# Emit (on VB.net): making a runtime class with an array field (fixed sized)

Tags: vb.net, reflection.emit

i should declare on runtime my own class. In this class there is an array element that should be fixed sized.
I try this code:

```
Dim an As AssemblyName = New AssemblyName("ClassLibrary1")
Dim assb As AssemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave)

Dim modb As ModuleBuilder = assb.DefineDynamicModule("ClassLibrary1", "ClassLibrary1.dll", False)
Dim tb As TypeBuilder = modb.DefineType("ClassLibrary1.Class1", TypeAttributes.Class Or TypeAttributes.Public)
Dim constructorArgs As Type() = {GetType(String)}
Dim cb As ConstructorBuilder = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public)

Dim fv As FieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("ia", GetType(Boolean).MakeArrayType, FieldAttributes.Public Or FieldAttributes.Static)

t1 = tb.CreateType()

assb.Save("ClassLibrary1.dll")

Dim t = Activator.CreateInstance(t1)
```

resulting in this:

[image]

As you can see "ia" field has no_size, how to fix it?
thanks for help

Matteo M.

Comment: The CTS (common type system) has no concept of VB-style fixed sized arrays. It’s simply an array that’s initialised to a given size.

Comment: ok, how to fix the size while calling the constructor? sorry but i am noob about reflection emit and constructors...

Comment: Write this class yourself first and it will become obvious how to write it with emit.  You will inevitably discover that you have to create the array object in a static constructor.  Since you didn't, right now it is nothing.

Comment: the class has to be like this:  'code'  public Class clsTag   Public Name as string  Public SetPointAlti(64) as integer   Public SetPointBassi(64) as integer   end Class 'code'  Anyone can help me please writing the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always found the best way to figure how to generate code is to let the C#/VB compiler do it and then use ILdasm to look at what it did. If you build your VB class and look at the generated IL you'll see this in the static constructor (your array is static, otherwise look in the instance constructor):

```
.method private specialname rtspecialname static 
        void.cctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       13 (0xd)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000: ldc.i4.s   65
  IL_0002:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0007:  stsfld     int32[] VBTest.clsTag:SetPointAlti
IL_000c: ret
} // end of method clsTag:.cctor
```

As you can see VB is `new`-ing the array with the desired size. That's what you need to do: add code to your class static constructor to create the array.

```
Dim cb As ConstructorBuilder = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public)
Dim sb As ConstructorBuilder = tb.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Static, CallingConventions.Standard, Type.EmptyTypes)
Dim fv As FieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("ia", GetType(Boolean).MakeArrayType, FieldAttributes.Public Or FieldAttributes.Static)
Dim ilgen = sb.GetILGenerator()
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, 65)
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, GetType(Boolean))
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Stsfld, fv)
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)

Dim t1 As Type = tb.CreateType()
```